# How to get a value of a label by query string from code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I passed the values of a two labels with ID  Me.Lbladid1 and Lbldortodorid to query string on myform1
I tried to retrieve these values into other labels on myform2 but only the first query string seam to work but the second returns a null value. Please help. This is my code

```
    'passing the values through query string
  Response.Redirect("myform2.aspx?adsid=" & Me.Lbladid1.Text & " & dortodorid=" & Me.Lbldortodorid.Text & " ", False)


   'retrieving the query string values on myform2
    me.label1.text= Request.QueryString("adsid")  'this works
    me.label2.text= Request.QueryString("dortodorid") 'this retuns null value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to remove the spaces from between the query arguments:

```
Response.Redirect("myform2.aspx?adsid=" & Me.Lbladid1.Text & "&dortodorid=" & Me.Lbldortodorid.Text , False)
```